# Return False is not working

Tags: javascript, cross-browser

```
if ((key > 57 || key < 48) && key != 46) 
{
  if(window.event)
  {          
    window.event.returnValue=false;       // IE
  }          
  else
  {
   ???????           

  }
}
```

Above code works for IE but it is not working for Firefox, Chrome and Safari. The return false is not working. Please guide me what I can write to return false in ???? area.

Comment: It'd be nice to see a bigger context, but I assume `return false` doesn't work?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1357118/event-preventdefault-vs-return-false

Comment: @troolee that question is mostly about jQuery handlers, which act differently.  If the OP was using jQuery he wouldn't be having these problems.

Answer (score 0):

What you do with the other browsers (and with IE9 in standards mode) is [`event.preventDefault()`](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Events/events.html#Events-Event-preventDefault) — *probably*. It depends a bit on how you're hooking up that event handler. But basically, IE's `returnValue = false` maps to `preventDefault` and IE's `cancelBubble = true` maps to [`stopPropagation`](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Events/events.html#Events-Event-stopPropagation).